# В IE не работает скрипт, скрывающий, показывающий блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<form class = "headerOfsearch" name="search" method="post" action="search.php" >
    <select name="taskOption" id="d1" onchange="searchfordate();">
        <option value="first">Обозначение</option>
        <option value="second">Дата проверки</option>
        <option value="third">Номер акта</option>
        <option value="fourth">Врем. промежуток</option>
    </select>

<input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Поиск"> <button type="submit">Найти</button>

    <section style="display:none;" id="new_form">
        <input type="date" name="bday">
        -
        <input type="date" name="lday">
    </section>

</form>
```

js

```
 <script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function searchfordate()
    {
         if(d1.selectedIndex == 3){
            $('#new_form').show();
         }
         else{
         $('#new_form').hide();
         }
    }

</script>
```

По задумке, при выборе из меню "Врем. промежуток", должна выскакивать строка для ввода даты. В хроме работает нормально, а вот в IE11 совсем не работает. Что делать? Я в это совсем новичок, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: А что такое `d1` вот тут `d1.selectedIndex`? :)

Comment: @Visman, я так понимаю, чтобы узнать по индексации, какой элемент селекта выбрал пользователь

Comment: Возможно IE не дает доступа к id из кода как к переменной, попробуйте сперва выбрать элемент по id, а потом манипулировать им.

Comment: У вас в других браузерах работает?

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko, должен давать. Он был первым, кто стал так делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно правильно определять ссылку на выпадающий список.

```js
function searchfordate()
{
//  if(document.getElementById("d1").selectedIndex == 3) // на чистом js
  if($("#d1 option:selected").index() == 3) // на jQuery
  {
    $('#new_form').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#new_form').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class = "headerOfsearch" name="search" method="post" action="search.php" >
    <select name="taskOption" id="d1" onchange="searchfordate();">
        <option value="first">Обозначение</option>
        <option value="second">Дата проверки</option>
        <option value="third">Номер акта</option>
        <option value="fourth">Врем. промежуток</option>
    </select>

<input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Поиск"> <button type="submit">Найти</button>

    <section style="display:none;" id="new_form">
        <input type="date" name="bday">
        -
        <input type="date" name="lday">
    </section>

</form>
```

Comment: Всё работает, только вместо календарей с датами (как в хроме), появляются просто два окошечка для ввода. То есть IE не поддерживает как таковой  <input type="date" name="lday"> ?

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий, судя по этим данным https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility его и FireFox не поддерживает.

Answer (score 0):

`JS`:

```
//Исполняется после полной загрузки страницы
<!--[if lt IE 9]>      
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function() {
                 if(d1.selectedIndex == 3){
                    $('#new_form').show();
                 }
                 else{
                 $('#new_form').hide();
                 }
        });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

или

```
//Исполняется после построения HTML
<!--[if lt IE 9]>      
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).ready(function() {
                 if(d1.selectedIndex == 3){
                    $('#new_form').show();
                 }
                 else{
                 $('#new_form').hide();
                 }
        });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: я, скорее всего, совсем тупой, но не работает(
Правильно ли я понимаю, что это всё над в <head></head> вставить?

Comment: Смотри, можешь это к конце body подключить. Проверь еще консоль в браузере, может быть jQuery не срабатывает.

Comment: Хорошо, а как это сделать?